# An H2 embedded database with oracle syntax?

Tags: database, spring, oracle

I have set my H2 datasource to be Oracle Mode both in the connector string and in my init script `SET MODE Oracle;`

However, many functions cannot be executed; such as the date `trunc` function, which is quite common in our code.

What is a practical way to test out my db applications? Looks like I may have to go back to my full-blown QA/Dev test oracle instance. Indeed, for anyone to implement a syntactical replica of Oracle would be a huge task, so I can imagine that any lightweight in-memory dbs for testing are going to miss many oracle features.

How do you generally approach this problem?

Comment: A practical solution is probably using HSQLDB for tests. It supports a lot of Oracle style functions including date `trunc`

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion unit testing and integration testing should be distinguished. Unit testing should not have any external dependencies, you should mock your DAO classes (eg: using Mockito). Testing against a real database should be done during integration testing.

As you might have seen the problem with using embedded database during unit testing is the syntax might be different to production database.

One approach to mitigate this is to setup an integration testing environment (eg: using Bamboo CI tool) where you have dedicated production-like (Oracle) database for testing. Test as much as you can using embedded database, but for those you can't test it later on your integration environment.

This integration testing environment would sit on its own server shared by the dev team members. Tool such as bamboo can auto detect when new commit is made, and launch the integration testing

Comment: thanks, I totally agree with the separation of integration vs unit testing. but sometimes some very basic and fundamental part of the code can only be tested with the aforementioned "integration" approach, so that after the developer has produced the code and associated unit testing suites, the code is far from safe. for example  if you have a query "INSERT INTO my_table  (good_field, BADD_field ) values (? , ?) ", and then you mock out ur jdbctemplate, you can only test that jdbc took in certain params, and you can't detect the error in the sql query (note "BADD_field" is a typo)

Comment: but in the above example, if you setup a real (either embedded or full-blown) db, it's very easy to detect the typo in the query. and normally I would test by writing the obj to db, then load it out with another method of the DAO that I'm testing, and then verify that what I wrote in is the same as what I load out.  

bottom line is that mock testing on the dao is very limited, sure we can isolate the testing of the service part by mock, but testing DAO itself with mock seems useless

Comment: You don't test DAO, but you test your service layer that uses DAO on unit test (by mocking it). DAO testing can be left for integration testing (eg: on Bamboo CI tool)

Answer (score 0):

I am just discovering some of the problems (different syntax for example). At least HSQLDB allows you to configure a "syntax mode".  For example:

You may configure it using this syntax (see the last part of the URL):

```
<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:PUBLIC:syntax.ora=true" />
    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
```

And I will allow hibernate to create the tables so I have a nice database abstraction for the ddl. But anyway it will have limitations. A testing database might be needed but if you are able to execute 90% of the tests with the embeded fast database it my be usefull.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Database Express Edition *is* Oracle Database, and because it's limited to 1GB of memory and one thread (as of version 11g), it tends to have a lighter footprint than the Standard or Enterprise editions.